# Is there any way to cast bitmovin stream video on tv using DLNA service?

Tags: video, casting, dlna, bitmovin-player

We are using bitmovin video platform for video streaming to cast on tv but the problem is that when we connect tv using DLNA service video is not casting on tv and other connection method is working fine. Is there any way to cast bitmovin stream video on tv with DLNA service. Please suggest.